# How do you use the `postconf -Me ...` option?

Tags: configuration, postfix

I'm trying to use the `postconf(1)` command to add a new entry to the `master.cf` file like so:

```
$ sudo postconf -e -M 'submission/inet=private=n unpriv=- chroot=y wakeup=- 
                       maxproc=- command=smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes
                       -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o syslog_name=postfix/submission'
```

*Note: broken up on multiple lines for nicer display here.*

This gives me an error as follow:

> postconf: fatal: invalid type field "unpriv=-" in "private=n unpriv=- chroot=y wakeup=- maxproc=- command=smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o syslog_name=postfix/submission"

I also tried without the field names:

```
$ sudo postconf -M 'submission/inet=n - y - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes
              -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o syslog_name=postfix/submission'
```

But that didn't help either:

> postconf: fatal: invalid type field "-" in "n - y - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o syslog_name=postfix/submission"

Also the `postconf -F ...` fails saying that there are no `submission inet` entries in the file. Just in case, I tried to also include the `-e` option, but that made no difference (`-e -M` or `-Me` and just `-M` are all equivalent according to the manual page).

Someone knows what the correct syntax of the `-M` option is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, annoying, isn't it, the way it is so badly documented.

Try:

`sudo postconf -M submission/inet="submission inet n - y - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o syslog_name=postfix/submission"`

And a `postconf -M | grep submission` will hopefully confirm your requirements.

Comment: Aaaah! You have to include the `submission inet ...` in the value. That's indeed unexpected since the name already includes that information.

Comment: It could also have been `<ip address/hostname>:submission/inet` if you wanted to limit it to a particular interface.